# What would be a simple use-case of a laravel job needing the SerializesModels trait?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm looking at the SerrializesModels trait in Laravel 5.2.  The one pertaining to Jobs and Queues.  Funny thing is, it never seems to actually serialize anything.  That function isn't even present.  To me it looks like it should be named FreshModels so the syntax would read use FreshModels.

Could someone explain when to/not to use this trait?

Comment: "That function isn't even present. " - what function?

Comment: serialize() function